# Replace & Evaluate for arrays

Tags: excel, vba

**Question 01: - Evaluate & Replace for array**

There is a code line:

```
x1 = Evaluate(Replace(fxn1, "x", x))
```

In which: fxn1 is string, says "x^2". The code line works fine for scalar value of x. However, when I go for x as matrix of (mxn) or even (nx1). It doesn't work.

Is there any way to make that code work?

My solution is using a loop to perform for every element in x. However, I don;t think this way is efficient.

**Question 02: Loop for above problem**
This is my temporary solution for my question above. It is not efficient.
The function works fine. However, when I use a sub to call that function. It does not works.

Here's the code:

```
Sub sample()
Dim fxn As String
Dim x() As Variant
Dim y() As Variant
fxn = "x^2"
x = Range("A1:A10")
y = fnarray("x^2", x)
Range("L1:L10") = y
End Sub

Function fnarray(fn As String, x As Variant)
Dim nr As Integer, nc As Integer
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim y
nr = x.Rows.Count
nc = x.Columns.Count
ReDim y(nr, nc) As Variant
For i = 1 To nr
    For j = 1 To nc
        y(i, j) = Evaluate(Replace(fn, "x", x(i, j)))
    Next j
Next i
fnarray = y
End Function
```

Comment: A problem with your function is that only a `Range` has `Rows` and `Columns` properties, yet you are trying to get those from a variant array.

Comment: So what should I edit here to make this works? I am not very clear here.Thank you

Comment: If you read a range into an array `arr`, the number of rows is `UBound(arr, 1)` and the number of columns is `UBound(arr, 2)`.

Comment: Also you'll want `ReDim y(1 to nr, 1 to nc)`.

Comment: @BigBen: Thank you. I also want to know when can we use sth.rows.count and sth.columns.count
If possible please help me explain more cuz I still cannot figure out what is wrong here. Thank you

Comment: When the argument is a `Range`. Then you would have `Set x = Range("A1:A10")`.